# is there a way to find out type of request like GET, POST from javascript web api

Tags: javascript, http

I used `window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource');` to get the list of resource requests. But I need to know what kind of requests they are.

The result of `window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource')` contains url name, starttime, duration ...etc.,. I tried googling it but i couldn't find anything useful.

Is there a way to find out what kind of requests they are like POST, GET using javascript web API?